# automate pattern matching for strings

Tags: design-patterns, matching, automaton

How can I create an automaton for searching pattern P="abaabba" with alphabet {a,b} ?

Comment: What language? What problem are you trying to solve? Can you give us some more context?

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions to match that pattern in some input strings.